# JSON-LD, is there any way to specify the default URI for the @id of a @type or the values of a property?

Tags: uri, json-ld

(I've already asked this on the W3/JSON mailing list, I'll try here too.)

I'm fairly new to JSON-LD, although I have significant experience with Semantic Web technologies.

I've read the guideline document (https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/) and I haven't get if the feature at issue is supported:

Suppose you have JSON objects of `@type` `Person` and `@type` `Address`, both having the `@id` property. Typical API-coming data will have values like integers or some internal, context-dependant IDs. It's pretty common to RDF-translate those values to prefix-based URIs like `http://www.example.com/Person/123` or `http://www.example.com/Address/xh324m44`.

What I would like to do is to specify those prefixes and keep data telling `@id` = `'123'`, with the value joins happening at RDF serialisation stage (the same specification would make it possible to do the opposite conversion too). Clearly, in such a use case, the prefixes depend on the `@type` of objects, and the `@base` mechanism is not enough. Moreover, it would be useful to have this mechanism available for properties too, e.g., to associate the address URI prefix to the values of the "address" JSON property.

It doesn't seem that this is currently available in JSON-LD, or am I missing something? Any plan for future extensions?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Oqhax, what do you mean? The programming language? None, Still studying the documentation and trying to understand the specifications (which are programming language-independent).

Comment: 1) So you want to prevent using prefixes for the values, correct? 2) What if an object has multiple types from different vocabularies, which vocabulary’s URI should be used then for `@id`? Or doesn’t this happen in your case? 3) I guess it should be possible to specify a `@base` per object. Would this work for you?

Comment: 1) no, I want to make prefixes avoidable, by predefining them and letting them to be implicit 2) good point, could be resolved by eg, priority rules 3) yep, not exactly the same (requires @base everywhere, doesn't allow for per-class/per-property associations), but I'm thinking of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **@base** in the context to create a URI base for values of **@id**, but this will not include something from **@type**. This sounds like something you might get by defining a URI template and using variables to expand type and id to create a URI. You can do this in a templating language and create the JSON-LD, but not directly in JSON-LD itself. Not likely to be a feature included by the language in the future, either, as it's application is pretty narrow.

Comment: Thanks Gregg, I cam to the same conclusion. Not sure it's so application-specific, but maybe it's too complicated and solutions like templating would ensure more separation-of-concerns.